# How can I test my app without iOS using Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, app-store-connect

I want to make some test with apple connect but I don't know if I need iPhone for this?

After want to connect Xcode with my developer account, I got## Heading ##:

Failed to create provisioning profile There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website.

What device? I don't have iPhone, but I have mac.
App works on simulator and app need to upload and then send on my team.

How can i do this without iPhone?

Regards

Comment: You are trying to export the application with which kind of distribution method (Ad hoc for example)?

Comment: You need at least one iOS device registered in your developer account to create a provisioning profile. Maybe you can get a UDID off a friend or family member and add it to the developer portal.